# Matlab external .m file function return

Tags: matlab

I have Main.m and External.m

I want to call a function in External.m from Main.m

Main.m code:

```
clc
External
disp('Press any key to go to advance')
pause
```

External.m code:

```
function f=EPD470_ObermeierC_Lesson05_MFile
    x=0:4:40
end
```

It does correctly display the values that I want:

```
x =
 0     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40
```

But then throws the error:

> Output argument "f" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
>   "EPD470_ObermeierC_Lesson05_MFile".

Edit:

I’m trying to display the value in Main.m that is returned by External.m

Changes

Main.m code:

```
clc
y=External
disp(y)
pause
```

(Edited to reflect typo)
External.m code:

```
function f=External
    f=0:4:40
end
```

It did not display the value I wanted.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? Your function is declared with output `f` and you never define `f`.

Comment: Change `x=0:4:40` to `f=0:4:40` and don't forget to assign the return value to something outside the function.

Comment: @excaza. It's easy to read error messages with years of experience. It's terrifying when you first start out. I'm just giving this guy credit for posting all relevant info and making the effort to print `x`. The question is very noobish, sure, but that's not a crime as long as it is proper.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I changed the External.m file to what you suggested. 
 I'm trying to display the y value in Main. m.  So I changed the code to y=External, but it doesn't display y automatically.  Then I tried disp(y) afterwards, but it also didn't display the value.  Sorry this is such a newbie question, but I just can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: @obizues. Add a follow-up edit to your question showing what exactly you tried. Don't modify the original part of the question because code modifications are very bad form, besides fixing transcription errors.

Comment: change `x=0:4:40` to `f=0:4:40`. That's all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added an edit as you asked.

Comment: Is there anything else in `External.m`? You should still be seeing `f=...` being printed if that function is called, because there is no semicolon after the assignment to `f`. You should then also see `y=...` printed, because there is no semicolon after that assignment either. So I guess your function is not actually being called. Is there another file with a similar name that is being executed instead?

Comment: No, that is all in External.m. What would a semicolon change in that situation?  Note: I edited the External.m function to reflect my scenario properly.

Comment: The difference between `f=1` and `f=1;` in MATLAB is that the first one echos the assignment to the command window, whereas the second one is silent. The statements without a semicolon in your code should be producing text in the command window. The fact that they are not, means that they are not being executed.

Comment: What do you want for it to display? 
From the code you provided, it will display: 
`f=0 4 ....40 `
`y=0 4 ....40 `
` 0 4 ....40 `

Comment: @Vairis I want it to display what you said it should display.  Right now it says "Too many output arguments" which leads me to believe that f=0:4:40 isn't assigning a return value to the call y=External

Comment: Nevermind, I accidently removed my "pause" before clc.  It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MATLAB! Hope you enjoy the language.

Below you will find updated code for External.m and Main.m (two options for Main.m), with lots of comments that explain why the changes were suggested.

External.m:

```
% generally it's best practice to name the function the same as in the
% filename. This won't impact the running of the code
function f = External

% change the main line of the function to assign the value to the correct
% variable name. Also, add a semicolon to the end of this line to suppress
% output (when a variable is assigned in MATLAB in a line that does not
% end in a semicolon, the MATLAB console displays that variable)
f = 0:4:40;

% the end command isn't necessary if just one function is defined in the
% file. Again, it won't impact the running of the code, but for simplicity
% it may be preferable to omit
```

Main.m - option 1:

```
% unchanged
clc

% assign the output of External to a variable. Note that the name of the
% variable used here may be the same as used inside the function, or it may
% not be the same. Note also that a semicolon is used to suppress output
x = External;

% explicitly display the variable
disp(x);

% unchanged
disp('Press any key to go to advance')
pause
```

Main.m - option 2:

```
% unchanged
clc

% assign the output of External to a variable. Note that the name of the
% variable used here may be the same as used inside the function, or it may
% not be the same. The absence of a semicolon on a line where a variable
% is assigned means that the MATLAB console will display that variable
x = External

% unchanged
disp('Press any key to go to advance')
pause
```